# How do I get Exaile to remember preferences?

Tags: indicator-sound, exaile

I'm using Exaile (with Sound Menu Indicator addon) and I would like the 'Show Tray Icon' and 'Minimize to Tray' preferences to remain true, but every time I close and reopen Exaile these revert to default (which is false). How do I get these preferences to stick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using this addon:

https://github.com/sunng87/Exaile-Soundmenu-Indicator

open

```
~/.local/share/exaile/plugins/Exaile-Soundmenu-Indicator-master/__init__.py
```

In a text editor and comment out (add # at begining) line 66:

```
patch_tray_icon(exaile)
```

This should do the trick. ;)